# How to prove 1+1=2 in Lean4 "inline"?

Tags: lean

I'm learnin to use Lean, specifically I'm at the existential quantifier, and I'm doing simple theorems to figure out how it works.

I've run into an issue I can't explain, namely that this code:

```
def even (n : Nat) : Prop := ∃(m:Nat), m+m=n

theorem even2 : even 2 :=
  have e : 1+1=2 := Eq.refl _
  ⟨1,e⟩
```

produces the following error:

```
type mismatch
  Eq.refl (1 + 1)
has type
  1 + 1 = 1 + 1 : Prop
but is expected to have type
  1 + 1 = 2 : Prop
```

while this code:

```
def even (n : Nat) : Prop := ∃(m:Nat), m+m=n

theorem plus11 : 1+1=2 := Eq.refl _

theorem even2 : even 2 :=
  have e : 1+1=2 := plus11
  ⟨1,e⟩
```

compiles just fine. I think it may have something to do with the difference between `have` and lambda application, but I get a similar error even when trying to refactor the code to use the latter rather than the former, so I'm probably wrong and I'm out of ideas.

So, how can I prove that 1+1=2, within the proof, without constructing an external theorem?

(Note: `by simp` seems to work, but I'd like to be able to do this without  tactics)

Comment: Lean's 1 is polymorphic and in the failing version, I think that elaboration has not yet decided that the type of 1 is Nat before `Eq.refl _` tries to prove it? You can see this by hovering over the 1's in the error and observing that their types all have metavariables in, `have e : (1 : Nat) + 1 = 2 := Eq.refl _` works. As to why this is happening, this I can't tell you. I just know from experience that adding type ascriptions sometimes helps.

Comment: Hopefully someone who knows the internals will chime in, but maybe it will be something to do with `theorem` forcing the type of the term to be decided before reading after the `:=` but `have` not doing so I guess? Note that for a general object with a 1, a + and a 2 there's no reason that 1+1=2 should be `rfl`. If you're talking about nats, then maybe it's best to say so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into the elaboration of your `have` using:

```
set_option trace.Meta.isDefEq.assign true
set_option trace.Meta.isDefEq true
def even2 : sorry :=
  have e : 1 + 1 = 2 := Eq.refl _
  sorry
```

We get two pieces of information:

- When trying to elaborate, the equality, lean tries to check whether `?m.55.1 1 1 =?= ?m.37.1`, where `?m.55` should be the addition operation, and `?m.37.1` should be 2.
- These two metavariables are assigned earlier during elaboration ! The elaborator does assign `?m.55 := instHAdd` and `?m.37 := instOfNatNat 2`.

All in all, this seems like a bug, or a misoptimisation, where the metavariables are not instantiated when checking for defeq, leading to the equality check getting stuck.

Comment: At the end of the day, the issue is that Lean has no idea which `1` you're talking about if you don't tell it, but sometimes it is forced to guess, and when this happens it guesses `Nat`. In the failing example it hasn't been forced yet, for whatever reason. The fix is to write `(1 : Nat)` if you're talking about naturals. Note that 1+1=2 is not proved by `rfl` in general.